# Why python randint(0,N) returns N?

Tags: python-2.7

Consider the MWE:

(the main idea is to choose a random point from a list and determine the farthest one from it):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean    

N = 5 # number of points
print( 'N = %d' % N)
x=[ randint(1,N) for p in range(0,N)]
y=[ randint(1,N) for p in range(0,N)]

pts = [[x[i],y[i]] for i in range(0,N)]
print pts

def dist_ponto_lista(ponto,lista):
    return [ euclidean(ponto,lista[j]) for j in range(len(lista)) ]

def ponto_mais_longe(lista_ds):
    ds_max = max(lista_ds)
    idx = lista_ds.index(ds_max)
    return pts[idx]

r=randint(0,N)
print r
P0 = pts[r]  # choose a random pt from pts 
ds = dist_ponto_lista(P0,pts)
PML = ponto_mais_longe(ds)
print P0
print ds
print PML

quit()
```

It appears to work well but some times, it gives an error, as below:

> ```
> N = 5
> [[5, 4], [3, 2], [5, 3], [4, 2], [1, 1]]
> 5
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "farthest-pts.py", line 25, in <module>
>     P0 = pts[r]
> IndexError: list index out of range
>
>
> ------------------
> (program exited with code: 1)
> Press return to continue
> ```

I really don't understand. In this case, `r=5` and so the error since `pts` index should be from `0` to `4` (remember `N=5`).

But why `r=5` was chosen since it was defined as `r=randint(0,N)`?

Comment: `r=randint(0,N-1)`

Comment: **What a shame!** From doc I got *`random.randint(a, b)`  Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.* So, I mixed with the one from `numpy` which is exclusive, ie, less than `b`. It would be good to have the same output. Sorry. I'll delete.

Comment: @Sigur: If you're using the non-`numpy` `random` module, for exclusivity on the high end you'd want `random.randrange`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking [at the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```
random.randint(a, b)
    Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).
```

What you maybe want to use is [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
numpy.random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype='l')
[...]
    high : int, optional
      If provided, one above the largest (signed) integer to be drawn from the
      distribution (see above for behavior if high=None).
```

This will give you your expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

```
P0 = pts[r]
```

by

```
P0 = pts[r-1]
```

since list are indexed from 0 to size-1!
Or you can also adapt the range of the randint to

```
r=randint(0,N-1)
```

As you prefer.

Last but not least, the error means that you are trying to access a cell of you array that is out of bound:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Hope it helps you!